# laravel bootstrap mb_internal_coding() undefined function

Tags: php

does anyone knows this problem?see the snapshot below i dont know what's going on i configure correctly the php.ini file

thank you so much for your time. your action is highly appreciated.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\mb_internal_encoding() in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php on line 1943

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); /*line 1943*/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reach the `mb_internal_encoding` function from the `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\` `namespace`. You need to explicitly tell the interpreter you intend to use the "root" namespace. So, instead of

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

use

```
\mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Comment: Did not work is a meaningless complaint. Please elaborate about how is it not working.